# my liferay portlet is not displaying anywhere in liferay 6.2 portal

Tags: tomcat7, eclipse-juno

I have created a portlet "GlobalLinkTranslation" and there are no errors or exceptions but still it is not showing neither in "Sample" nor in "Content"  in liferay portal.I am using liferay-6.2.0
 I am getting one message in my eclipse console:

- [liferay/hot_deploy-1][ResourcesImporterHotDeployMessageListener:212]
  Group or layout set prototype already exists for company liferay.com

Please help me guys

Thanks and Regards 
manish payasi